# IFC express model parser in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, express, ifc

does anyone has or had the problem of creating  an EXPRESS schemar parser in C# (preferably)?
I would also like the tool to create a parser/file generator for importing the models/ versions of IFC standards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There a two more C# libraries for IFC:

- [xBIM Toolkit](http://xbim.codeplex.com/)
- [IFC Engine](http://www.ifcbrowser.com/)

If you want to be able to use a user-defined EXPRESS Schema and you are also familiar with C++ you can try to modify the [IfcGearsExtender](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ifcgears/downloads) so it generates a C# Code instead of C++ Code.

[oipExpress](https://bitbucket.org/Vertexwahn/oipexpress/src/default/) could also be an option for you to generate a custom C# binding for you.